# React Native Updates - react-navigation not working

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

My React Native Versions are as below

```
>react-native -v
react-native-cli: 2.0.1
react-native: 0.49.5
```

I am trying just to redirect from one to another screen with my old demo it was working fine with react-navigation but now

This is my app.js

```
import {
    StackNavigator,
} from 'react-navigation';

import Login from './login';
import Register from './register';

const Nav = StackNavigator({
    RootScreen: {screen: Login},
    RegisterScreen: {screen: Register}
});

export default class App extends Component {  
    renderScene(route, navigator){
        if(route.name == 'login'){
            return <Login navigator={navigator} />
        }
        if(route.name == 'register'){
            return <Register navigator={navigator} />
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <Login />
            </View>
        );
    }
}
```

And here is login.js from where if user is new to app will redirect to register screen

```
import { StackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';

export default class Register extends Component {

    static navigationOptions = {
        title: 'Register',
        header: null
    };

     constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            txtUserName:'',
            txtEmail:'',
            txtPassword:'',
            txtConfPass:''
        };
    }


    render() {
        return (    here is design for and button which calls _signUpPage function );   
    }

    _signUpPage = () => {
        const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;
        this.props.navigation.navigate('Register');
    }
}
```

But it returns an error of

```
TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.props.navigation.navigate')
```

Please check error image

[image]

Comment: is `signupPage` component part of the stacknavigator? Can you add your navigation structure to the question please

Comment: @bennygenel please check, I have updated my question.

Comment: I think you are mixing old react native navigator usage with react-navigation usage. I suggest you to take a look at [this hello world example](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/intro/basic-app) of react-navigation.

Comment: Thank you very much @bennygenel  I will try this demo and update you if its working for me or not. Thanks again for demo link, and yes I have implemented demo 2 or 3 months ago and now its totally different from it.

Comment: where are you calling this `renderScene` function. From your syntax it seems you are using the old Navigator of React-Native which isn't available in v0.49.5 of React-Native.